# ¿Como saltar datos repetidos de un arreglo con foreach? en jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, foreach

la siguiente es para ver como podria saltarme datos usando forEach,
lo que ocurre es lo siguiente, yo tengo un arreglo, y debo recorrerlo con forEach para que posterior imprima eso, pero, resulta que dentro de mi arreglo tengo datos que se me estan repitiendo, y quisiera ver como se podria saltar ese dato y que continue con el ciclo

dejo aqui mi codigo:

```
 if (data && data.data && Array.isArray(data.data)) {
          data.data.forEach(function (incidencias) {

              $('#incidencias').append(generateIncidencias(incidencias.cedula, incidencias.npcPerson));
          });
        }
      },
```

Se que debo usar if o un swich, pero no se como aplicarlo aqui ya que no se como hacer referencia al dato como usualmente es con un for normal, en este caso quisiera que el dato a usar en la condicional sea el de incidencias.cedula.

De antemano gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Crea una variable auxiliar, te guardas en la variable auxiliar la que estás iterando y comparando con la que estás recorriendo y en un if puedes comparar la actual con la auxiliar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te creas un array dentro del bucle y le vas agregando el valor clave por el que quieres identificar los duplicados, luego al principio del bucle colocas una validación para verificar si ese id esta dentro del array que estas construyendo, si ya esta pues no lo procesas y sigues con el siguiente.

Algo así:

```
 if (data && data.data && Array.isArray(data.data)) {
      var ids = [];
      data.data.forEach(function (incidencias) {
          if($.inArray(incidencias.cedula, ids) === -1) { // No esta duplicado 
              $('#incidencias').append(generateIncidencias(incidencias.cedula, incidencias.npcPerson));
              ids.push(incidencias.cedula);
          }
      });
    }
  },
```

Espero te sirva, saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio :"), lo que no comprendo aun del todo, es, el arreglo creado dentro del bucle, osea, como se relaciona el incidencias.cedula con el ids y porque la condicion seria === -1?, y no la informacion dentro del array osea como una cadena o algo como  ==== 'cedula'

Comment: El arreglo "ids" es para almacenar en el todos los valores "incidencias.cedula" considerando que ese es el valor por el que quieres detectar los duplicados. Para luego usando la función de jquery $.inArray() poder verificar en cada iteración si la cedula esta en ese arreglo "ids" para no volverlo a procesar. La condición "===" es una constumbre personal, puedes ponerlo "==" y te funcionará igual. el "===" se usa cuando quieres comparar valor y tipo de datos que sean iguales. Puedes consultar la función $.inArray() en el siguiente enlace: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray

Comment: oh vale vale, entiendo, es como si usaramos el indexOf(), para obtener el valor de -1 y decir que el dato se encuentra, para saltarlo, cha muchas gracias!!!!! :")

Answer (score 0):

Esta es mi solución, creo un array auxiliar, y preguntas al auxiliar si contiene la posición por la que se está iterando, solo se añade si no lo contiene.
Y te almacena cada dato sin repetir.

```
var sinRepetir = [];
if (data && data.data && Array.isArray(data.data)) {
   data.data.forEach(function (incidencias) {
   if(!sinRepetir.includes(incidencias)) {
       sinRepetir.push(incidencias);
   }
   $('#incidencias').append(generateIncidencias(incidencias.cedula, incidencias.npcPerson));
 });
}
```

sinRepetir contiene los datos únicos.
Espero te sirva.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte :")